Reduce in function with generics that uses extends is not accepting empty object that is valid
I have the following piece of code:
const translateConvertedIdentifiers = <T extends BaseQueryResponseRow>(rows: T[]): T[] => {
  return rows.map((row) => {
    const convertedRow = Object.entries(row).reduce<T>((acc, [key, val]) => {
      return { ...acc, [key]: val };
    }, {});

    return convertedRow;
  });
};


The type that it extends is the following:
export type BaseQueryResponseRow = { [column: string]: any };


I get a type error that says that I am not able to use {}
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BaseQueryResponseRow'

However, even an empty object is of type BaseQueryResponseRow, why doesn't it allow it ?
when I use as T it works but I am looking at it as my last resort for this function.
what should I do to solve this properly ?

{} extends BaseQ⋯seRow and T extends BaseQ⋯seRow doesn't imply {} extends T (no more than "cats are animals" and "dogs are animals" implies "cats are dogs"). Surely {} is almost certainly not going to be a valid T (e.g., call tra⋯ers([{ a: 0 }]), so T is {a: string}. Is {} a valid {a: string})? Only after the reduce() runs is the result likely to be a T. TS can't deduce that, so as T is the way to proceed if you want this to be accepted. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

You could use a type assertion for the accumulator, it's valid imo in such cases since you cannot properly construct the accumulator with T type since you don't know what actual T will be passed to the function
Playground
type BaseQueryResponseRow = { [column: string]: any };

const translateConvertedIdentifiers = <T extends BaseQueryResponseRow>(rows: T[]): T[] => {
  return rows.map((row) => {
    const convertedRow = Object.entries(row).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
      return { ...acc, [key]: val };
    }, {} as T);

    return convertedRow;
  });
};


So the answer here is just "it's valid imo"? The question already mentions being able to use as T "as a last resort".  This doesn't look like it tries to answer "why doesn't TS allow it"

@jcalz updated, hope it's more clear, additional to your comment under the question
